# Angular: increment based on given number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Given the code:

```
<section class="calendar__day--view" ng-init="weekday = date.firstWeekdayOfMonth" ng-model="weekday">
    <div ng-repeat="bill in data.budget.bills">
        <div ng-if="bill.weekday === weekday || bill.date === $parent.$index">
            <strong>{{bill.name}}: {{bill.amount}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

where `date.firstWeekdayOfMonth` is the day of the week (0-6 [sun-sat]) the 1st is on, how could I increment `weekday`?

For example, if the 1st of the month was on a Friday (5), how would I increment?

EDIT: here is the parent ng-repeat:

```
<div class="calendar__day col-xs-12 col-md-1" ng-repeat="day in calendar.daysInMonthArray" tabindex="0">
    <span class="calendar__day--number">{{day + 1}}</span>
    <app-calendar-day-view></app-calendar-day-view>
</div>
```

Comment: where & how do you want increment it?

Comment: I believe increment would be `weekday++`, but what do you want to do after incrementing? Your `ng-repeat` will always have `5` in it, the 1st weekday.

Comment: I edited the code to show a better picture. I have a data object `(data.budget.bills)` that, when its `bill.weekday` (0-6) or `bill.date` (day of month [0-30]) matches, I want it to show that bill. We can ignore the `bill.date` part, as it's working and not relative to the question. Let me know if I can clear this up further.

Comment: Your code seems a bit strange for what I understand as your purpose.  What is the reason for the ng-model on the section tag? If this is a daily view why not just send it the data of the given day or build a dayView directive that handles all of the logic behind the scenes ?

Comment: @yccteam, it probably seems strange, because I don't really know the best way to approach this. This is a nested ng-repeat and is its own directive called `<app-calendar-day-view>` inside of its parent view called `<app-calendar-view>`. The only way I could get `weekday` to be set to `date.firstWeekdayOfMonth` was to set it in `ng-init`. I then hoped I could just set the model value to `weekday` then increment that model.

Comment: I updated the code above to show the parent ng-repeat, if that helps shed light anywhere.

Comment: I think i understand now. My suggestion is to prepare the data in the calendar directive itself.  It seems like you repeat all days and then repeat all the data for each day and show only what is relevant for the current day.  Why not prepare your days in the calendar directive (this could be easily done using the .map method) and then inject the day's model to the dayView directive?